# MERN Cannot Get / when deploying to Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, package.json, favicon, mern

My app works on on my local server but when I deploy to heroku, I get this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkXIz.png)

I cannot find anything wrong in my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config();

//mongoose 
mongoose.connect(process.env.URI || 'mongodb://localhost/book_trak', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));
db.once('open', () => console.log('we are connected'));

const app = express();

//body parser no longer needed 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())

app.use(cors())
app.use('/book', require('./routes/book'));
app.use('/author', require('./routes/author'));

if(process.env.NODE.ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'front_end', 'build')));


  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'front_end', 'build', 'index.html'))
  });

}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('running on Port ' + PORT));
```

I think the issue might be in my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.0"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "cd front_end && npm install",
    "start": "node index",
    "server": "nodemon index",
    "client": "cd front_end && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently \" npm run server  \" \" npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd front_end && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.7"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

For some weird reason, my heroku logs are not showing any errors and when I push to heroku it says build succeeded.

Comment: Hey friend, this is not proper etiquette but I need help. My apps on Heroku but it only displays the backend.  My app seems very much like yours, given the files you posted (did you learn from travesy MERN tutorial?) Anyways, are you using `path` to fix that? And is there any other way I need to use `path` other than what you have here in your index.js file?

Answer (score 1):

Problem SOLVED!!!

There was a typo:

```
if(process.env.NODE.ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'front_end', 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'front_end', 'build', 'index.html'))
  });

}
```

should have been:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
```

I used  . instead of _

Answer (score 1):

```
try this it may help you!!

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "production"){
    app.use(express.static("./client/build"));
    const path = require("path");
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {`enter code here`
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));

    })
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).